# Webm support in mediaelement.js with fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, mediaelement.js

I'm trying to make the wonderfull [mediaelement/fancyvideo](http://www.picssel.com/play-mp4-videos-with-mediaelement-js-in-fancybox/) work with a webm support (because the flash fallback is choppy with MacOs Firefox) : 
- if there's a webm file, it's played.
- if not, mediaelement uses it's flash fallback.
For now, I've tried to set

```
this.content = "<video id='video_player' poster='" + _videoPoster + "' width='" + _videoWidth + "' height='" + _videoHeight + "'  controls='controls' > <source type='video/mp4' src='" + _videoHref + ".mp4'/>  <source type='video/webm' src='" + _videoHref + ".webm'/>  </video>";
```

That's working a soon as you write your video without extension... BUT forget about the flash fallback if only mp4 and no webm is there. 
I suck at Jquery and other JS stuff, maybe someone has an idea. It might be a very cool feature for this plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You still could target any `mp4` file (or any other type) in your `<a>` tag like :

```
<a href="video.mp4" class="fancy_video" data-width="560" data-height="320" data-caption="the video" data-poster="">Play Video</a>
```

Then you may need to strip the *extension* of the file using the `.split()` method and build the different `sources` within the `beforeLoad` callback  like :

```
beforeLoad: function () {
    // build the HTML5 video structure for fancyBox content with specific parameters
    _videoHref = this.href.split(".mp4")[0]; // remove file extension from href
    // set fancyBox content and pass parameters
    this.content =
        "<video id='video_player' width='" + _videoWidth + "' height='" + _videoHeight + "'  controls='controls' preload='none'>" +
        "<source src='" + _videoHref + ".webm' type='video/webm' />" +
        "<source src='" + _videoHref + ".mp4' type='video/mp4' />" +
        "</video>";
    // ...etc.
}
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e8nogpcu/)**

**Notice** all source files MUST have the **same name** regardless their *type* and *extension*.

Comment: That's a good way to keep the file extension. But the link must have a .webm substitute... If not, nothing is played.<br> Would it be possible to target the webm file and, if it returns "undefined", to make mediaelement choose the mp4 one. Then... FLASH FALLBACK ! <br> I keep working on it. Thanks for help !