# fancybox loads all content on pageload

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, fancybox, fancybox-2

I use fancybox in combination with a small self made cms.
The users can upload a movie onto the server with a titel and some info and a thumb. and the script below prints all the thumbs on a page. and all the video's in display none divs which get showed whenever the right thumb is clicked like this:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM movies";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

//prints out all the thumbs on the main page:

echo ' <a class="various" href="#inline'.$row['id'].'" title="'.$row['info'].'">
<div data-content="'.$row['titel'].'" data-html="true" class="image">
<img src="thumbs/'.$row['thumb'].'" alt="" />
</div>
</a>';

//generates all the video's. whenver the link with inline 1 is clicked above. the video with inline 1 will show up
echo '<div style="display: none;">
<div id="inline'.$row['id'].'">
<video width="720" height="480" controls>
<source src="movies/'.$row['movie'].'" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
 </div>
</div>';
}}

?>
```

This all works fine when I have 4 video's a page. But as soon as I display 12 video's on each page the buffering is going really slow. so the first few video will load fine. but when you try to watch the lets say 8th video you have to wait a long time because it is buffering the seven before the 8th first.

So my question is. is there anyway to only start loading the video that gets clicked?

my fancybox js:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".various").fancybox({
            'titlePosition'        : 'inside',
            'transitionIn'        : 'none',
            'transitionOut'        : 'none'
        });

    });
  </script>
```

hope anyone can help me out!

NOTE: A way to prevent the video's fromn loading directly would be to give the video element:

```
preload="none"
```

But I prefer the video's to be auto played whenver they opened so that is not really an option.

Comment: I think it's not a good idea to load videos inline but on-demand and until they are required. Further more, you can cover a broader range of browsers and devices using the [mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) plugin. I wrote a tutorial that you can see **[here](http://www.picssel.com/play-mp4-videos-with-mediaelement-js-in-fancybox/)** ... also you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26766263/1055987 for reference how-to add different video sources (using the same tutorial)

Comment: @JFK Heey. thanx for this awesome solution! really love it. 1 quick question tho. The fulscreen option doesnt work. in the fancybox controlls the fullscreen option is no clickable and when I use the controls of the media player to go fullscreen it only displays a black screen on firefox and a white screen on chrome. so just a fullscreen blank frame. any idea why? I tried it with your github code. You can watch it here: http://lucbrefeld.com/new-site/test/test.html

Comment: It seems the full screen issue you mention appears in the recent MEJS v2.16.1 (non existing in previous versions.) I will update my post explaining why this issue appears and how-to address it. Stay tuned ;)

Comment: Well, there are some other issues apart from the fullscreen. In the mean time I would advise you to use MEJS v2.15.1, which doesn't seem to have compatibility issues with the method in my tutorial (so far)